# Plotable versus Plottable

Tags: orthography

On rare occasions, whether it be a Tuesday or not, when I write about plots, as in graphs, I see spell checker complaints where both alternatives are rejected.  Is it plotable or plottable?

Comment: Possibly "I dislike the stackexchange question quality checker for obvious reasons" is relevant, but I don't see why (and don't understand what you mean) so have downvoted the question.

Comment: It should have been worded a bit better, but is a valid question. Try to at least give context in the future to clarify the intended meaning, in case of confusion, please. BTW, good luck with determining whether each word gets a double consonant or not, since there are some exceptions that take a single one, just to spite us.

Comment: @jwpat7, I have reworded the question to omit the comment about the quality checker.

Comment: I was about to un-downvote, but then got stuck trying to fathom the relevance of "whether it be a Tuesday or not".  (BTW, more-usual form is "...a Tuesday or *no*".)

Comment: Interesting. I will start a thread on the "Tuesday or no" thing.

Comment: @jwpat7, It seems the quality checker preferred to see the thing about Tuesday included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double "t."

It ends in a vowel + consonant: "plot." So it's "plot-plotted-plotted" as well.

Comment: Is there a web application that would tell you this rather than just reject both spellings?

Comment: There may be a decent dictionary app available for use. I use a dictd server on a linux box, at least primarily. Otherwise http://www.wordnik.com/ is handy as it sources multiple sites.

Comment: @shinyspoongod, wordnik.com rejected plotable and defined plottable. That beats a conventional dictionary but it's still a dictionary, not a mechanical turk that would tell you what Cool Elf's answer did.

Comment: @broiyan Indeed. Mechanical turks are hard to beat, unless you have a bit stick.