# "whether it be a Tuesday or not"?

Tags: grammar

There is a claim at this link [to another stackexchange question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71628/plotable-versus-plottable) that the usual form is "On rare occasions, whether it be a Tuesday or no, I will go to the supermarket." as opposed to "whether it be a Tuesday or not".

I thought it would be the opposite so I'd like to see it resolved here, please.  Is the usual form geographically specific?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Whether it be a Tuesday or no* is a stylised construction used only for special effect. It would normally be expressed as *whether it’s a Tuesday or not*, or something similar.

Comment: I would describe it as "archaic" rather than "stylised", but otherwise I agree.